# Reducing space between icon and label name

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below form in react.

[image]

I need to reduce the space between the list-icon and the label. I am using the below CSS for the same.

```
.form__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form__container input {
  color: rgb(115, 0, 255);
  size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;

}

.form__container li ul {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Below is my react component.

```
  return (
      <div>
        <FormValidator emitter={this.emitter} />
        <div >
          <form encType='multipart/form-data' action={this.props.form_action} method={this.props.form_method}
 className='form__container'>
                { this.props.authenticity_token &&
                  <div style={formTokenStyle}>
                    <input name='utf8' type='hidden' value='&#x2713;' />
                    <input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value={this.props.authenticity_token} />
                    <input name='task_id' type='hidden' value={this.props.task_id} />
                  </div>
                }
                {items}
              </form>
              <div>
                {validationList}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please verify if you're showing the right react component. I can't seem to relate the ui with the jsx code. Also, try inspecting the checkboxes to see the styles applied there

Comment: Your `.form__container` has 3 nested inputs elements. Each `input` element has a defined width of 300px.  Try modifying the `width: 300px;`.

Comment: Actually form is getting delivered by backend. its dynamic form. there can be n component but in a row I need only 2 component. thats why we cant see all the input tag in the react component

Comment: which one @ThomasVanHolder ?

Comment: @Mahima, in your CSS file change the `width: 300px` value in the class `.form__container input`

Comment: Thank you.Thomas, I am checking the same.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you just need to use input[type=text]
See my demo below:

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
      <label for="fname">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" /> Check me!</div>
</form>
```